# A command-line or batch cmd to concatenate multiple files

Tags: windows, command-line

I have 10 sql files in one directory

Is there a command-line method to concatenate those files **including the filename** **and its content** of each one into a single file?

for example finalfile.sql should look like this

```
   sql1.sql
   '
   'sql1 content.....
   '
   sql2.sql
   '
   'sql2 content.....
   '
   etc
```

I'm using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Given an .sql file is plaintext only, yes, you can do it with standard batch commands.

**You need the following knowledge bits:**

- Printing file contents to console: `type <filename>`
- Printing custom output to console: `echo <mytext>`
- Printing a newline: `echo.` (should work in this case)
- Redirecting console output into a file: `sometext > <outputfile>` (appending to a file with `>>`)
- Grouping outputs to redirect: Enclose with parenthesis `( ...) > <outputfile>`
- Optional: Iterating over all files in a directory: `for /f` (see `for /?` if this is needed)

**Example: sqlmerge.bat**

In the following quick&easy example, I assume that you know the filenames of the 10 sql files and that you do not need a script which will work for an arbitrary amount of files.

The batch file "sqlmerge.bat" (chose your name as you like) would look like this:

```
@echo off

(
echo sql1.sql
type sql1.sql

echo.
echo sql2.sql
type sql2.sql

echo.
echo FILENAME
type FILENAME

...continue copy&paste-adding above example block for the other needed files...

) > finalfile.sql
```

The batch file must be run inside the same directory the *.sql files are in. In the same directory the output file will be created.